# How to set properly the loss function of my neural network with keras functional API?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Im basically trying to make a neural network to predict 4 different variables. 1 variable is categorical with 3 possible outputs, and the other 3 variables are continuos.

Im using the keras functional API to define this neural network:
[Neural Network Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aeoaz.png)

But when I try to run my model I get this error massage:

***ValueError: The two structures don't have the same sequence length. Input structure has length 4, while shallow structure has length 2.***

This is my code:

```
#Start with the input layer, where we must indicate the shape of the Data passed to the model. 
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(37,))

#Add dense layers to the input layer. These layers are commom to both predicted variables. 
x = Dense(units=74, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = Dense(units=74, activation='relu')(x)

#Add the output layer for the type using Sigmoid activation. Theres 3 possible outputs
#so i decided to use 'softmax' as activaction
y_t_layer = Dense(units = 1, activation='softmax', name='y_t_layer')(x)

#Here we diversificate the model adding a new Dense layer to the Base layers (x)
quality_layer=Dense(units=148, name='quality_layer', activation='relu')(x)

#The output layer for the other 3 continuos variables. It's added below the Dense Layer: quality_layer 
y_q_layer = Dense(units=3, name='y_q_layer')(quality_layer)

#The Model is created indicating the inputs and outputs. 
#We have only one Input, but we can create models with multiple inputs. 
#The name in outputs is the same of the variables, and the internal name of the layer. 
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[y_q_layer, y_t_layer])

#I tested two optimizers and choosed Adam, but feel free to test yourself. 
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.0001)
#optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

#To compile the model we use two dictionaries, to indicate the loss functions and metrics 
#for each output layer. Note that the name of the layer must be the same than the 
#internal name of the layer. 
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, 
              loss = {'y_t_layer' : 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
                      'y_q_layer' : 'mse'
                     },
              metrics = {'y_t_layer' : 'accuracy', 
                         'y_q_layer': tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()

                       }
             )
```

I've been doing some research about similar problems and I have the understanding that I need to define properly the **loss functions** but Im not sure how to do it.

Comment: It's most likely linked to the shape of your labels that you use during the training of the model. Can you share a mock example of your data/data pipeline?

Comment: First of all change your softmax layer 'y_t_layer' to have 3 nodes instead of 1.

Comment: My data is a 96x37 (96 examples with 37 features), and my target variables is basically a 1x4 vector (y[0],y[1],y[2],y[3]) where y[0] to y[2] are continuos variables and y[3] is the vector with 3 different possible values (1,0,-1).